# Don't have a LinkedIn, but interviewer suggested we connect

Tags: interviewing, linkedin

I just had a non-technical interview with a company I'm pretty excited about, and at the end the interviewer told me to feel free to add him on LinkedIn. I don't have a LinkedIn (have been intending to make one for a while but didn't get around to it yet). Would it look bad if I made one and connected with him without being connected with anyone else? I know I have to start somewhere, but I'm just wondering if being so unconnected/a newbie would be more harmful than helpful.

I don't expect a LinkedIn connection to be the deciding factor over whether or not I get called back for a technical interview, but I don't want to risk anything/if it'd be beneficial, there's no reason for me to not do it.

Comment: It was just a suggestion, up to you if you do or not, I'd say it won't make a difference

Comment: Are you asking the Internet if you should follow through with your plan to create a LinkedIn account? Just go ahead, it's not a question of life and death.

Comment: If it makes you feel better Linkedin will often suggest connections for you based on information you've entered, or emails you have used, so if you like you can connect with several people at once instead of just the one interviewer.

Comment: Your former school/university friends and current colleagues (if relevant) could also become your first contacts. Anyway creating a linkedin account can't do any bad...

Answer (score 7):

It won't matter either way. But in general, it's good to have a LinkedIn profile. And it won't look bad if this interviewer happens to be the first person linked.

I'd go ahead and create one, then link to the interviewer (and anyone else who you want in your professional network).

No need to overthink this one.